# How to destroy fragment and never come back to him

Tags: android, android-fragments

I switch fragments by navigation. I decided to add welcome screen with fragment to my app.  I made welcome fragment as home fragment, so app starts with welcome fragment. After the welcome, I need to automatically switch to another fragment and destroy the starting fragment so that it can no longer be returned.But when fragment switches,the welcome fragment is visible under the new fragment. I solved it by `android:background="?android:windowBackground"`. Now the new fragment overlaps the welcome fragment, but the welcome fragment still remains under the new fragment, and when I press the back arrow on the device, the welcome fragment appears again.I also removed the toolbar from the welcome fragment, and when the fragment switches, I show the toolbar, but the toolbar from the welcome fragment is displayed on the new fragment.Help my please. How to destroy welcome fragment and never come back to him?

This is main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
        R.id.nav_food_text_analysis, R.id.nav_recipe_analysis,R.id.welcome_fragment), drawerLayout)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

}

This is MainActivity xml file

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/toolbar_background"/>

      </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:navGraph = "@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activiy_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is Welcome Fragment

```
    private lateinit var topAnimation: Animation
    private lateinit var bottomAnimation: Animation

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome_screen, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()



        topAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.top_animation)
        bottomAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.bottom_animation)

        image_diet_girl.animation = topAnimation
        welcome_text.animation = bottomAnimation




        Handler().postDelayed({
            (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(
                    R.anim.enter_from_right,
                    R.anim.exit_to_right
                )
                .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, FoodAnalysisFragment())
                .commit()
        },6000)


    }

}
```

Navigation xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/welcome_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_food_text_analysis"
        android:name="com.example.nutritionfacts.ui.foodTextAnalysis.FoodAnalysisFragment"
        android:label="Food analysis"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_food_text_analysis" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_recipe_analysis"
        android:name="com.example.nutritionfacts.ui.recipeAnalysis.RecipeAnalysis"
        android:label="Recipe analysis"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_recipe_analysis" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/welcome_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.nutritionfacts.ui.welcomeScreen.WelcomeScreen"
        android:label="welcome screen"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_welcome_screen" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Typically when you use the Android Navigational Component, the fragments are created everytime the navigation to that fragment is called.  Can we see your navigation xml?

Comment: @Kristy Welsh I added navigation xml

Comment: @Kristy Welsh Look at the code in the welcome fragment  in Handler(). this is how I automatically switch the welcome fragment to another